# How to efficiently create an array by tracing back the parent nodes in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am working on a path planner algorithm. I have a Nx2 matrix **NodeInfo** which has the current node number in its 1st column and parent node number in its 2nd column. For example:

```
NodeInfo = [3,1;
            4,1;
            5,2;
            6,2;
            7,3;
            8,4;
            9,4;
           10,4;
           11,5;
           12,6;
           13,6;
           14,6;
           15,7;
           16,7;
           17,8;
           18,8;
           19,9;
           20,9;
          21,10;
          22,10;
          23,11;
          24,11;
          25,12;
          26,12];
```

When the algorithm reaches to a goal it outputs the node number, which is 26 in this case. I am looking for a smart way of tracking back the parent nodes and creating an array of the nodes that resulted with the goal node. So the output should be:

```
Array = [26, 12, 6, 2];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 p = NodeInfo(end,1);
 parents = [p]
 while (~isempty(p))
  p =  NodeInfo(find(NodeInfo(:,1)==p),2)
  parents = [parents p]
 end
```

The answer is stored in the `parents`

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses a [container](http://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html?lang=en), and it may take some time to build up a hashmap, but it might faster than `find()` when there is actually a larger dataset with a vast number of requests.

**Edit:** Added 2 nodes into `NodeMap` to prevent `isKey()` function in while condition from wasting too much time.

```
NodeMap = containers.Map(NodeInfo(:,1),NodeInfo(:,2)); %Create a container
NodeMap(1)=0; NodeMap(2)=0;                            %Add 2 nodes
nodes=zeros(1,length(NodeMap));                        %pre-allocate  
k=2; [N,nodes(1)]=deal(26);                            %Init parameters     
while(N>0)                                             
  [nodes(k),N]=deal(NodeMap(N));
  k=k+1;
end
nodes(nodes == 0)=[]                                   %Cleaning up & print
```

The output of `N=26` is:

```
nodes =

    26    12     6     2
```

*hope it helps!*